# Mysql for Excel addin not connecting to localdb connection

Tags: mysql, excel

Please can someone please help!

I am currently trying to open a connection to a database on the Mysql for Excel addin. I am currently using WAMP for my local connection and mysql port 3306. When I try establish the connection it seems to be busy for a very very long time until i eventually terminate excel. I am using excel 2010 32 bit version and Windows 7.

I manage to reconise and make the same connection through Mysql Workbench.

Thanks in advance.